# Understanding how to create a montage of images for data visualization?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I read a reference code for creating a montage of images, and there's a few lines of code I don't quite understand.

This is the full code:

```
def montage(images, saveto='montage.png'):
    """Draw all images as a montage separated by 1 pixel borders.

    Also saves the file to the destination specified by `saveto`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    images : numpy.ndarray
        Input array to create montage of.  Array should be:
        batch x height x width x channels.
    saveto : str
        Location to save the resulting montage image.

    Returns
    -------
    m : numpy.ndarray
        Montage image.
    """
    if isinstance(images, list):
        images = np.array(images)
    img_h = images.shape[1]
    img_w = images.shape[2]
    n_plots = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(images.shape[0])))
    if len(images.shape) == 4 and images.shape[3] == 3:
        m = np.ones(
            (images.shape[1] * n_plots + n_plots + 1,
             images.shape[2] * n_plots + n_plots + 1, 3)) * 0.5
    else:
        m = np.ones(
            (images.shape[1] * n_plots + n_plots + 1,
             images.shape[2] * n_plots + n_plots + 1)) * 0.5
    for i in range(n_plots):
        for j in range(n_plots):
            this_filter = i * n_plots + j
            if this_filter < images.shape[0]:
                this_img = images[this_filter]
                m[1 + i + i * img_h:1 + i + (i + 1) * img_h,
                  1 + j + j * img_w:1 + j + (j + 1) * img_w] = this_img
    plt.imsave(arr=m, fname=saveto)
    return m
```

For the creation of m, I get the idea that the author is trying to create a scaffold of sorts to multiply the image on later, but how is the value of `images.shape[1] * n_plots + n_plots + 1` calculated? Why must the ones be multiplied by 0.5?

Why can't it be images.shape[1] * n_plots only, since the shape should b sufficient for the number of images that could be included in the montage?

Comment: Did you try it and find the result lacking in some way?  Did you refactor with the *changes* you suggest, then try it?- what happened?

Comment: Perhaps [the library](https://github.com/pkmital/CADL/blob/master/session-1/libs/utils.py) you got that from uses the 0.5 values for something.

Comment: ```Why can't it be images.shape[1] * n_plots only,```?? - From the first line of the docstring - ```Draw all images as a montage separated by 1 pixel borders.``` - I imagine you have to account for the borders.

Comment: I have tried to remove the parts and did `images.shape[1] * n_plots` only, but I see no noticeable difference. I'm however worried this might just work for this instance. I'm unsure of the mathematical reasoning behind this formula.

Comment: Put ```print(n_plots, images.shape, m.shape)``` just before the return statement -it will give you numbers to look at.  If you have two images (```n```) that are 10 pixels wide and you put them side by side, the result  ```10 * n``` (20) pixels wide. If you put a 1 pixel border around each you need to add one on the left side of each image, ```+ n```, and you one on the right side of the last image. ```+ 1```.

Comment: Perhaps the 0.5 multiplier is used to help distinguish between original image pixels and pixels that were added.  None of the image pixel values will equal 0.5. You could make your border any color you want by substituting your color value for all pixels that equal 0.5. The 0.5 values *define* the individual image *spaces*.

Comment: @wwii thank you so much for your explanation. This seems to be what the author is intending. However, with just one pixel, bordering the images, could the images be easily demarcated from one another? Or is one pixel too insignificant to act as a border?

Comment: It is certainly significant enough if you are inspecting it numerically.  Have you tried to use it yet? Can you see the borders?

Comment: I've recently tried to use images of a different size, and turns out the borders become apparent once the images go out of the defined lines. I suspect this will be particularly useful to separate the images if the background is homogeneous in colour (e.g. the mnist images with black backgrounds).